# Traefik v2: HTTPS returns `404 page not found`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, traefik

I followed the [quick start guide](https://docs.traefik.io/getting-started/quick-start/)  and I use a basic `traefik.toml`:

**traefik.toml**

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[api]
  dashboard = true
  insecure = true

[providers.docker]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    ports: 
    - "8080:8080"
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - "$PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)"
```

The call of the HTTP endpoint:

```sh
$ curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://127.0.0.1
Hostname: aa6bfee60f2d
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 172.29.0.4
```

Call of the HTTPS endpoint:

```sh
curl --insecure -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost https://127.0.0.1
404 page not found
```

**My Problem**: It returns **404 page not found** instead of the whoami-content as done by the HTTP endpoint.

How do I enable **HTTPS** in Traefik v2 correctly?

A full (not woring) MWE can be found here: https://github.com/boldt/traefik-v2-mwe/

Comment: Maybe try adding this label: `traefik.http.services.whoami.loadBalancer.server.port=80` ? Worked for me for some weird reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

> the backend service is running on HTTP mode. This means that this configuration is not full HTTPS.

> port 8082 is used for metrics. if you don't have metrics you can remove it. Remove the configurations from `traefik.yml` and `static.yml`.

> change the port `traefik.http.services.my-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8484` by your service port.

**traefil.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4.6
    command: --providers.docker
    restart: always 
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      - web
      - internal
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 28080:8080
      - 8082:8082
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik/static.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./traefik/dynamic.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic/dynamic.yaml
      - ./certs/localhost.crt:/etc/traefik/certs/traefik.crt:ro
      - ./certs/localhost.key:/etc/traefik/certs/traefik.key:ro
```

**static.yml**

```
log:
  level: DEBUG
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: web-secure
  web-secure:
    address: ":443"
  metrics:
    address: ":8082"

providers:
  docker:
    watch: true
    exposedbydefault: false
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/dynamic
    watch: true
    filename: dynamic.yml
    
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

metrics:
  prometheus: 
      buckets:
        - 0.1
        - 0.3
        - 1.2
        - 5.0
      addEntryPointsLabels: true
      addServicesLabels: true
      entryPoint: metrics
```

**dynamic.yml**

```
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/traefik.crt"
      keyFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/traefik.key"
      stores:
        - default
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/traefik.crt"
        keyFile: "/etc/traefik/certs/traefik.key"
```

**my-service.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-service:
    image: my-service
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./certs/cacerts:/opt/java/openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts:ro      
      - ./certs/keystore.p12:/opt/java/openjdk/jre/lib/security/keystore.p12:ro      
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-service.rule=Host(`my-service.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-service.entrypoints=web,web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-service.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-service.service=my-service"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.my-service.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.my-service.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.my-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8284"
```